# How to check if a div overflow the page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div whose height can sometimes overflow the page's height because of a long content. How to know if it is the case? I tried to compare scrollHeight to clientHeight, but both values are the same. Here is the code:

```js
const Component = ({text}) => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const contentOverflowPage =  ref.current && ref.current.scrollHeight > ref.current.clientHeight

  return (
    <Root ref={ref}>
      {content}
    </Root>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: if your root doesn't have `overflow:hidden` and fixed `height` it will take same height as the `children`

Comment: I can't give the div a height nor an overflow hidden because it must display all the available text. I need to compare its position to the the global window's available height, but I don't know how to do it in a efficient manner.

Comment: so you want to get the document height ? did you try ` window.innerHeight`?

Comment: yes, so I could compare ref.current.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight. But I need to add the distance the div has from the top of the window to offsetHeight in order to be accurate.